# Could not start vanilla kernel on virtual machine

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 installed. It is the host for 3 virtual machines (also running Ubuntu 11.10) installed using KVM.

I need to recompile the kernel of each virtual machine for setting some networks options, but when trying to boot on the new kernel I get the following:

> Gave up waiting for root device".... "ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/(ID)
>   does not exist".

What I have tried:

1. rootdelay 50, 60, ... didn't work
2. booting with pci=nomsi (and other options)... didn't work
3. Deleting the partition and starting from scratch... got the same
   error.

Additional info:

1. The kernel on my PC and VMs is 3.0.0.12-generic-pae
2. The kernel I am trying to compile is 3.0.1
3. There is no /etc/fstab when trying to boot from the new kernel
4. The uuid that the new kernel is not finding is exactly the one I see
   on the /etc/fstab of the original kernel

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess; have you compiled in virtio block support to your new kernel if you're using it?

You probably want some/all of the following (certainly won't hurt to turn them on to try anyway):

```
CONFIG_VIRTIO
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK
CONFIG_VIRTIO_NET
CONFIG_VIRTIO_CONSOLE
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BALLOON
```

I suspect the top two are most important for this particular problem. If you're not using virtio then this is irrelevant, just say and I'll delete.

Comment: I already got it solved, this is the correct answer (for my case at least)